# How to derive a definition of definite integral from another definition

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, definite-integrals, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

Consider the following exercise:

> If $f$ is uniformly continuous in $[a,b]$ then show that $$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{b-a}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f\left(a+\frac{i(b-a)}{n}\right).$$

The definition of Riemann integrable I have is:

A function $f$ is Riemann integrable in $[a,b]$ if and only if there is a number $L\in\mathbb{R}$ such that for every $\varepsilon>0$ there is a partition $P_{\varepsilon}$ such that the inequality $$\left|S(,f,P;\xi_0,...,\xi_{n-1})-L\right|<\varepsilon$$ holds for every partition $P=\{a_0,...,a_n\}$ finer than $P_{\varepsilon}$ and every election of points $\xi_i\in\{a_i,...,a_{i+1}\}.$ The number $L$ is defined as $$L=\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx.$$ And $S(f,P;\xi_0,...,\xi_{n-1})$ denotes the Riemann sum of $f$ with respect to a partition $P$.

Is it necessary to use that definition of integral to prove the exercise? If so, how can I do it? Any help is welcome.

Comment: The essential hint is here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/314028/42969

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for the hint. However, I am still unable to see how to derive one definition from the other

Comment: A continuous function on a compact interval [a,b] is uniformly continuous

Comment: Use your definition to establish the definition based on norm (mesh) of partition (the proof is difficult). Then the result in your question uses uniform partition (subintervals are of equal length)  and as number of intervals tends to infinity the norm tends to $0$. The result holds for any Riemann integrable function and continuity is not necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Further hint:

With $x_i = a+\frac{i(b-a)}{n}$, we have $x_{i+1}- x_i = \frac{b-a}{n}$ and

$$\left|\int_a^b f(x) \, dx -  \frac{b-a}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f\left(a+\frac{i(b-a)}{n}\right)\right|= \left|\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\int_{x_i}^{x_{i+1}} f(x) \, dx -  \frac{b-a}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f\left(x_i\right)\right|\\= \left|\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\int_{x_i}^{x_{i+1}} [f(x)-f(x_i)] \, dx \right| \leqslant \ldots $$

Comment: How did you get the left hand side of the second absolute value? I mean everything that is before the minus sign. I understood everything but that. Thanks!

Comment: @user926356: Are you asking why $\int_a^b f(x) \, dx = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\int_{x_i}^{x_{i+1}} f(x) \, dx$?

Comment: You know that if $a < c <b$ then $\int_a^b f(x) \, dx  = \int_a^c f(x) \,dx + \int_c^b f(x) \, dx$ -- correct? Use that repeatedly for $a = x_0 < x_1 < \ldots < x_{n-1} < x_n = b$.

Comment: Thanks! That was precisely what I was asking. I understand now

Comment: @user926356: You’re welcome. I assume you know the next steps: apply triangle inequality and bring in uniform continuity of $f$ to show LHS < $\epsilon$ when $n$ is large.